# When I smith my weapons, the damage on the weapons go down?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My Ebony Bow was at first showing 78 damage - but when I look at the damage it does when I'm about to smith, it says 28 or somewhere in the twenties. After a few minutes, it then says 78 again. I'm not sure what actually happened, but this happens every time I smith.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 28 damage is the raw base damage of that type of weapon. When you see 78 after smithing, that's including all smithing and one/two/archery, etc damage perks added.

Comment: Thanks. Also, I was able to smith my ebony armor and ebony bow but now I am unable to. I have the ebony ingots but whenever I click to improve the weapon it says something like: 'you lack the perk to improve this item'. Or something like that. Why does it say that?

Comment: @David Sounds like you have enchanted those items since then.  You need the Arcane Blacksmith perk to improve magic items.